# Vaadin14 - how to set Helper Text above the field in ComboBox

Tags: java, spring-boot, frontend, vaadin, vaadin14

I know there is a way like this

```
listBox.addThemeVariants(CheckboxGroupVariant.LUMO_HELPER_ABOVE_FIELD);
```

But ComboBox does not have **addThemeVariants**. So How we can set the helper text above the field.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
combo.setItems("foo", "bar");
combo.setHelperText("Oh no");
combo.getElement().getThemeList().add(CheckboxGroupVariant.LUMO_HELPER_ABOVE_FIELD.getVariantName());
```

Comment: Basically you can use any "LUMO_HELPER_ABOVE_FIELD" enum value, since they all convert to the same string value in the browser. And ComboBox will propagate that theme attribute value to the internal TextField component.